# Protractor test passes but cant see search field populate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

My test case works but the problem is I cant see my any keys sent to my search input box type in by protractor when my script runs.

---

1 spec, 0 failures

Finished in 7.696 seconds

[14:53:55] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running

[14:53:55] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

homho3031261:Homeshp jonathan.hofler$

---

Any help would be appreciated.

---HTML CODE---

```
<input parse-search-query=""
       type="text"
       tabindex="1"
       name="search_query"
       autocomplete="off"
       placeholder="Search by City ST, Zip, or Address"
       data-ng-model="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.searchParams.search_query" 
       data-ng-change="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.clearErrors()"
       data-focus-on="focusQuery || form.search_query.$error"
       data-uib-typeahead="suggestion as suggestion.label for suggestion in searchQueryFieldCtrl.getSuggestions($viewValue)"
       data-typeahead-focus-first="false"
       data-typeahead-min-length="0"
       data-typeahead-wait-ms="300"
       data-typeahead-on-select="searchQueryFieldCtrl.setSearch($item)" 
       class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope"
       aria-autocomplete="list"
       aria-expanded="false"
       aria-owns="typeahead-69-869">
```

---conf.js---

```
describe('New stack hompage test', function() {
  it('should test home page title and search', function() {

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
        browser.sleep(3000) 

        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:3000/');

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Find Homes for Sale, Rent & Real Estate Listings Nationwide at Homes.com');

        var search = element.all(by.css("input[name='.search_header.search_query']"));

        search.sendKeys('Chesapeake VA'); // this is not working
        browser.sleep(3000); 

        // search.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).preform(); // this is not working

        // var searchT = element.all(by.css("input[name='.homepage_hero search_query']"));

        // search.sendKeys('anything'); // this is not working

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title of this question, I'm assuming you're asking why the test is passing even if the search field is not present/you cannot see the test send keys.

Your test passes because your only assertions are based on the Url and title:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:3000/');
expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Find Homes for Sale, Rent & Real Estate Listings Nationwide at Homes.com');
```

You need a test for the search input as well.  To check the text for an input, you don't use `getText()`, but rather `getAttribute('value')`.  So you could do:

```
expect(search.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Chesapeake VA');
```

As far as your locator goes, it looks incorrect which is probably why it's not sending keys.  First, you're creating an `ElementArrayFinder` since you used `.all`.  Second, you should not have a period before `search_header` as that indicates you are looking for a class.

Try this:

```
var search = $('input[name="search_query"]');
```

The `$` is simply shorthand for `element(by.css())`.  And if you used `.all` because there are multiple elements, then either add `.first()` to the end of that locator, or use `.get(1)` (or whatever the index would be):

```
var search = $$('input[name="search_query"]').get(2);
```

`$$` is shorthand for `element.all(by.css())`

Finally, since you're using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, I would advise you to start using [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).  Something like:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(search)).then(function() {
   search.sendKeys('Chesapeake VA');
});
expect(search.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('Chesapeake VA');
```

Comment: Thanks you i will try this

Comment: should var search = $$('input[name="search_query"]').get(2);
come before or after var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; ?

Comment: doesn't matter, those are both just declarations.  Define both of them, then call `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(search));` before you use `sendKeys()`;

Comment: Thanks everything works thanks for explaining the $ i understand protractor better now.

Answer (score 0):

`search` is type ElementArrayFinder, which doesn't have `sendKeys`method. You want to use `.then` to wait for the promise to return an array of ElementFinders, and then use sendKeys there. Check the docs:

[ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)

[sendKeys](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys)

Comment: so after looking at the documentation should it be this way .then(search.sendKeys.("Chesapeake VA");? or
.then.search(sendKeys("Chesapeake VA");? I am sorry i am new at using protractor.

Comment: or could it be   .then(sendKeys('Chesapeake VA'); ?